# Xamarin.iOS app project App doesn't recognize GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Sign in for Xamarin.iOS app.i have added the package Google Sign-In for iOS required for Sign in process.had Setup AppDelegate, added GoogleService-Info.plist to the Xamarin.iOS app project.
when i run the build it displays an error below.

**[Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.**

**Error configuring the Google context: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.greenhouse error -3.)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that the file is in your {Project}.iOS build and that the file is exactly called "GoogleService-Info.plist".
Also be sure that you set the build action of the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to: BundleResource

For a full tutorial take a look at: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging (this is a link for cloud messages but the first part is the same for all firebase services)

Comment: This link no longer exists :(

Answer (score 14):

In *Visual Studio for Windows*,

Include the **GoogleService-Info.plist** file in the IOs project root,

[image]

Then right click on the **GoogleService-Info.plist** file and go to **Properties**. Under Properties, set **BundleResource** for *Build Action*,

[image]

That's all you have to do . Now just clean the project, delete the *bin* and *obj* directories, then run the project

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 4):

1. Open "GoogleService-Info.plist" and change any `<true></true> or
   <false></false>` to `<true /> and <false />`
2. Reopen the xamarin solution
3. It should work now, worked for me.

Copied from [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/107318/xamarin-forms-ios-part-fcm-cant-open-googleservice-info-plist)

Answer (score 1):

Open "GoogleService-Info.plist" in editor and change any  or  to  and 
Reopen the xamarin solution
It will work now

Answer (score 0):

For me (besides other problems already mentioned here) the Problem was that GoogleService-Info.plist was ticked for "iOS Optimization" in the Properties resulting in unreadable gibberish after building.